# All possible forward combination of words in a line using Scala

Tags: scala

Suppose I have a line in my textFile = `"a b c a b"` and I want output as = `(a,b) (a,c) (a,a) (a,b) (b,c) (b,a) (b,b) (c,a) (c,b) (a,b)`.
What I have done so far is using combination defination of Scala but it is not giving the duplicate occurence.

```
val combinations = textFile.flatMap { line =>
     line.split("[\\s*$&#/\"'\\,.:;?!\\[\\](){}<>~\\-_]+")
        .combinations(2).toList 
        .toSeq
        .map{ case arr => arr(0) -> arr(1) }
```

}

By doing this I am getting output as:

```
(a,a)
(a,b)
(a,c)
(b,b)
(b,c)
```

Is there any other way to get the output which I want because I do not think combination will work here?

Comment: The `permutations` function does not take a int param like combinations. Maybe, you could try `(list.combinations(2) ++ list.combinations(2).map(_.reverse)).toList`. This gets you the combinations in both directions. You could end up with duplicate pairs for pairs like `(a, a)` - you could remove these by doing `.toSet.toList`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a built-in function, that does this, so I believe you'd have to do it manually:

```
val items = line.split("[\\s*$&#/\"'\\,.:;?!\\[\\](){}<>~\\-_]+").toList
val pairs = for {
  first :: rest <- items.tails.filter(_.nonEmpty)
  second <- rest
} yield (first, second)
pairs.toList
```

`tails` method returns an iterator of tails of the sequence. For your example `items.tails.filter(_.nonEmpty)` returns an iterator with those lists:

```
List(a, b, c, a, b)
List(b, c, a, b)
List(c, a, b)
List(a, b)
List(b)
```

Then you split each of those lists into the `first` element and the `rest` with the `first :: rest` pattern match, and make pairs of the `first` element with each element from the `rest`.

Comment: Thanks kolmar, I am able to use this logic for a list of strings. But I am reading from a file which has many lines and I have to do it for all of them. So here I am using - val items = textFile.flatMap{line=>line.split("[\\s*$&#/\"'\\,.:;?!\\[\\](){}<>~\\-_]+").toList} , but this wont work because items will be of type rdd string and tails is used for type list i guess.

Comment: @Sam Can you put this whole block of code into `textFile.flatMap`? E.g. `textFile.flatMap { line => val items = ... val pairs = ... pairs.toList }`

Comment: Note that an explicit `filter` is not necessary, the pattern matching of the `for` takes care of that automatically.

Comment: Thanks kolmar, I put that code inside and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

Split the input, convert it to list, use `tails` and a `for`-comprehension:

```
val input = "a b c a b".split(" ").toList
val result = for (h :: t <- input.tails; x <- t) yield (h, x)
```

The result is the following:

```
result foreach println
```

prints

```
(a,b)
(a,c)
(a,a)
(a,b)
(b,c)
(b,a)
(b,b)
(c,a)
(c,b)
(a,b)
```

...or just use a nested `while`-loop with two explicit indices `i` and `j` into an array...

Answer (score 2):

The `combinations` method is defined to remove duplicates so you can't use that for your solution.

There is a simple recursive solution:

```
def combos(letters: List[String]): List[(String, String)] =
  letters match {
    case Nil =>
      Nil
    case c :: tail =>
      tail.map(d => (c, d)) ::: combos(tail)
  }
```

This is not tail recursive so it may slow and memory-hungry, so here is a tail-recursive version if you care more about performance than clarity:

```
def combos(letters: List[String]) = {
  @tailrec
  def loop(letters: List[String], res: List[(String, String)]): List[(String, String)] =
    letters match {
      case Nil =>
        res
      case c :: tail =>
        loop(tail, res ::: tail.map(d => (c, d)))
    }

  loop(letters, List.empty[(String, String)])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case if you are looking for different ways of doing it:

```
val myList = "a b c a b".split(" ").zipWithIndex
for (x <- myList; y <- myList if x._2 < y._2 ) yield (x._1, y._1)
```